# How to get Firebase Project Name or ID from Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using Cloud Functions and want to get the project name from within one of my Javascript server files.  I know that value is stored in the .firebaserc, but I don't think that file is available on the server, right?  I want to do something like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.getProjectName();  // or getProjectID()
```

or

```
functions.getProjectName();
```

Comment: A quick search on the [firebase-samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/search?l=JavaScript&q=project&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93) seems to hint towards `process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT`

Comment: You can also populate your own configuration values into your Cloud Functions environment.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Thank you @Frank.  The answer is:
`process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT`.
I'm not sure where the variable `process` comes from, but this does work to get the project name.

Comment: process is a global object in node. See: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_process

Comment: Doesn't appear to work on the GCF Node 10 runtime. Don't see it when dumping `process.env`

Comment: Might be better to use `process.env.GCP_PROJECT` now instead since `GCLOUD_PROJECT` has been marked as deprecated here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#environment_variables_set_automatically

Comment: Neither GCLOUD_PROJECT nor GCP_PROJECT are available in Node 10 runtime.

Comment: `GCLOUD_PROJECT` seems to work now, it was fixed in the `node10` runtime too https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/437

Comment: works as of July 2022

Answer (score 28):

Firebase admin SDK has access to that information for you.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const projectId = admin.instanceId().app.options.projectId
```

Comment: This may not exist depending on how admin was initialized

Comment: admin.instanceId() is deprecated https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.instanceId.InstanceId-1

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me. (node 10)

```
const FIREBASE_CONFIG = process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG && JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
const projectId = FIREBASE_CONFIG.projectId;
```

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
const projectId = admin.instanceId().app['options_'].credential.projectId
```

Answer (score 4):

From [the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables):

> `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG`: Provides the following Firebase project config info:
>
> ```
> {
>   databaseURL: 'https://databaseName.firebaseio.com',
>   storageBucket: 'projectId.appspot.com',
>   projectId: 'projectId'
> }
> ```

Note that since it's a JSON string you need to parse it like this:

```
const projectId = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId;
```

Alternatively you could use the [`firebaseConfig()` method](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/57ca58a1e3b8a4db652bc31e477c8b95fa5899a3/src/v1/config.ts#L59) from the `firebase-functions` package in your Cloud Functions, like so:

```
import { firebaseConfig } from "firebase-functions";
const projectId = firebaseConfig().projectId;
```

Additionally, Google Cloud Platform (which Firebase runs on top of) will automatically populate the [environment variables documented here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#runtime_environment_variables_set_automatically), depending on which runtime you're using.

Comment: `firebaseConfig()` is nice (and by now it seems documented)

Answer (score 3):

Firebase Functions provides a library that retrieves the project ID out of the box:

```
const { projectID } = require("firebase-functions/params");
console.log("My project ID: ", projectID.value());
```

[Docs for reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.params.md#paramsprojectid)

Comment: Best answer for v2 functions in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

For cloud functions running on newer versions of Node:

```
import firestore from "@google-cloud/firestore";

const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();
const projectId = await client.getProjectId();
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to retrieve the project ID using admin SDK is

```
admin.appCheck().app.options.credential.projectId
```

This also works in headless setups like Docker where the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is set.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using `app.INTERNAL.credential_.projectId`.
This is clearly not save, but so far there is no cohesive way to get it (AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of the answers given above:

```js
function getProjectID() {
  return firebaseInstance.options.projectId ||
    (firebaseInstance.options.credential && firebaseInstance.options.credential.projectId) || '';
}
```

Or in TypeScript:

```js
function getProjectID(): string {
  return firebaseInstance.options.projectId ||
    (firebaseInstance.options.credential && (firebaseInstance.options.credential as unknown as { projectId: string }).projectId) || '';
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use `functions.config().firebase.projectId`

PS the easiest way to initialize app is `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);`

Comment: functions.config().firebase.projectId is not defined for me. I'm only seeing fields: databaseURL, storageBucket, apiKey, authDomain, and credential on the functions.config().firebase object.

Comment: `functions.config()` returns environment configurations set by the user, which is why you are getting downvoted.