# firebase get current project name react

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Is there a way to retrieve the current project name that was activated through `firebase use project-name`? I've set up several projects in firebase as different environments. Since using the same codebase my problem is that the script doesn't know which configurations to use.

Found this related issue [process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078037/how-to-get-firebase-project-name-or-id-from-cloud-function) and according to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) it's automatically populated but only seems to return undefined.

So I have a config and using it like this;

```
const config = {
  prod: {
    apiKey: ...
  },
  stage: {
    apiKey: ...
  }
};

const config = process.env.ACTIVE_ENV === 'production' ? prodConfig : devConfig;
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when I run `firebase use stage-proj` it will populate the right config details and also for running `firebase deploy`.

Comment: Please edit the question to share more details.  Do you have code that uses that environment variable?  How are you running it?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?