# Set up different firestore dbs for different projects with same repo for CI/CD dev and prod sites

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-build

I have two firebase projects with a CI/CD pipeline that deploys to production if I push to master and develop if I push to my develop branch. My .firebasesrc is like so:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "host-test-xxxxx"
  },
  "targets": {
    "host-test-xxxxx": {
      "hosting": {
        "production": [
          "production-xxxxx"
        ]
      }
    },
     "host-test-dev": {
      "hosting": {
        "develop": [
          "develop-xxxxx"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my firebase.json is:

```
{
  "hosting": [{
    "target": "develop",
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "target": "production",
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

The target is currently set to default and I have a firestore set up in that project. I want to create a file that gets the config of the current target something like this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "$myAPIKEY",
    projectId: "$myPROJECTID",
    appId: "$myAPPID",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


export default firebase;
```

I'm confused how I get this information from the project. I want this information to be different if I change the project ID using a google cloud build trigger variable, so that if I deploy to production I get the database in the production project, and if I deploy to develop I get the develop db.

Comment: Please have a look into the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44121001/8791788). Please let me know if it works for you because it's not specifically for Cloud Build if not for Cloud Functions.

Comment: I think I did see that and used a similar method. I will post a detailed answer to my question at some stage because I have solved this problem, but the solution was quite complex so I might write a Medium article and link or something